# Is it possible to use curl_multi_getcontent and CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION together?

Tags: php, curl, asynchronous, callback, curl-multi

I have an asynchronous curl crawler which works well without `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION` enabled.

I am trying to limit the amount of data downloaded with `CURLOPT_WRITEFUCNTION` by stopping any downloads that go over 1mb in size.

The problem I am having is that `curl_multi_getcontent($done['handle'])` doesn't return any data when I use `CURLOPT_WRITEFUCNTION`.

I know I can play with the data inside of `CURLOPT_WRITEFUCNTION`'s function, but it would make things much easier if `curl_multi_getcontent($done['handle'])` continued to do it's job in conjunction with `CURLOPT_WRITEFUCNTION`.

Is it possible to use curl_multi_getcontent and CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION together?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15906261/parallel-curl-request-with-writefunction-callback/15958698#15958698

Comment: @awons no, unfortunately. His posts have been the only ones I have found concerning CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION and curl multi with php, and he has no idea what he's talking about... it doesn't matter where you place CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION in the setopt array, I just tried placing it at the end and there was no difference in outcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my own question is this:

CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER is basically a built in WRITEFUNCTION.

When you specify another WRITEFUNCTION, you override CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER and thus have to RETURNTRANSFER yourself if that's what you're trying to do.

I wish the php curl package would have thrown an error along the lines of "warning: CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION overrides CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER" but I'm sure they have their reasons for not doing so.